# Wiki in Teams/Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, office365, onenote, microsoft-teams

we are using Office 365 for our development (Teams for communications and files, which are than stored on Sharepoint. Azure DevOps for agile development). I am struggling to find the right place to manage a central wiki. The Teams wiki for each Channel doesn't support search and you don't get any notifications about new articles. Also in Sharepoint you will only see MHT files, which aren't helpful.

Therefore I tried OneNote with a central wiki notebook that I created in Teams as a tab. This Notebook can also be opened from Sharepoint.

Would this be the best approach? Is there a way to create a NewsFeed in Sharepoint for new OneNote Articles and Changes? Or is there an even better option?

Thanks!

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic in [SO]. But IMHO the wiki in Teams is too annoying (can't directly edit the markup, as is per team); SharePoint in just user hostile. So we use Azure Dev Ops wiki. If you want it to be cross project then create a new team project to just host a wiki (if you want change notifications, subscribe to pushes on the underlying git repository).

Comment: Changed to the Azure DevOps Wiki which seems to work fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While all solutions were good, I switched to Azure DevOps Wiki with a single project as this seems to satisfy all requirements the best way. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the SharePoint modern pages if you need to share a wiki with a larger audience. For a small audience, OneNote wiki should work fine as well.

When someone opens the SharePoint modern pages you're by default in read-only mode and you can also specify who has read or edit access.

To notify people (internally) you can use the [Alert Me](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-alert-to-get-notified-when-a-file-or-folder-changes-in-sharepoint-e5a79e7b-a146-46da-a9ef-d65409ba8918#Pick_tab=Online) on the Site Pages library. I have no idea on how to do this in OneNote...

If the wiki is technical, I would place it as close as possible to the repository. In your case Azure Devops.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Confluence (Atlassian) and maybe connect it to Sharepoint via an SSO. You'd be able to search through it and it's way faster and user friendly than other alternatives.